# How to calculate the mean average of 2 different rows

Tags: math, statistics, average, mean

| country | Value |
| --- | --- |
| GBR | 10 |
| USA | 30 |
| GBR | 20 |
| USA | 40 |

This is just a quick question which i was hoping someone could help me sort out as i am new to coding. How would i be able to find the mean / average value of the total values which occur in GBR and then the values which occur in USA? Thanks :)

Comment: Which language? also, which data structure / API are you using to store this table?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are a pandas data frame and python (please update the language and data structure in question tags).

For getting group-wise means you can use `groupby` -

```
import pandas as pd

#df contains the dataset!!

df.groupby('country')['Value'].mean() #Grouped by country, get mean of column value
```

```
country
GBR    15
USA    35
Name: Value, dtype: int64
```

You can read more about this on this [article](https://www.kaggle.com/akshaysehgal/how-to-group-by-aggregate-using-py) I wrote on kaggle